# как реализовать вывод значения функции в lable?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

**Здравствуйте!**
Никак не получается вывести return функции в lable tk.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app = tk.Tk()


global ans
global kurs2
ans = '' 

k1_label = ttk.Label(app, text='Валюта 1')
k1_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

k1_text = ttk.Entry(app, width=10)
k1_text.insert(0, 'btc')
k1_text.grid(row=0, column=1)

k2_label = ttk.Label(app, text='Валюта 2')
k2_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

k2_text = ttk.Entry(app, width=10)
k2_text.insert(0, 'usd')
k2_text.grid(row=1, column=1)

def curs_php():
    url = 'https://www.calc.ru/kurs-PHP-RUB.html'
    page = requests.get(url)
    r = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    get_kurs = soup.find_all('div', class_="t18")[1].select('strong')[0]
    kurs = str(get_kurs).split(' ')[3]
    return float(kurs)

def get_etc():

    x = k1_text.get()
    y = k2_text.get()

    if y == 'php':
        try:
            url = 'https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/{}-rur'.format(x)
            response = requests.get(url).json()
            price = response['ticker']['price']
            p = float(price)
            g = p/kurs2
            c = round(g, 3)
            ans = x.upper() + ' ' + str(c)+ ' ' + y.upper()

        except:
            return 'no data'
    else:
        try:
            url = 'https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/{}-{}'.format(x, y)
            response = requests.get(url).json()
            price = response['ticker']['price']
            p = float(price)
            c = round(p, 3)
            ans = x.upper() + ' ' + str(c)+ ' ' + y.upper()

        except:
            return 'no data'



k3_label = ttk.Label(app, text=ans)
k3_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn_gen = ttk.Button(app, text='Запросить', width=15, command=get_etc)
btn_gen.grid(row=2, column=1)

print(ans)

kurs2 = curs_php()
curs_php()

app.mainloop()
```

заранее спасибо!

Comment: А что делает этот скрипт?

Comment: по паре названия валют например btc-rur возвращает цену btc в рублях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Будут вопросы пишите**

```
import requests
from tkinter import Tk, mainloop
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Entry, Button

URL = 'https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/{0}'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
    Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'}

class App(Tk):
    price = round
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Курс валюты')
        self.interface()

    def interface(self):
        title = Label(self, text='Введите валютную пару в формате xxx-xxx')
        title.config(font=('Times', 12))
        title.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.currency_pair = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.currency_pair.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=4)

        self.showing_price = Label(self)
        self.showing_price.config(font=('Times', 12))
        self.showing_price.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.button_run = Button(self, text='запросить')
        self.button_run.config(command=self.returning_exchange_rate)
        self.button_run.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def returning_exchange_rate(self):
        print(self.currency_pair.get())
        response = requests.get(URL.format(self.currency_pair.get()), 
            headers=headers).json()
        data = float(response['ticker']['price'])
        self.price = round(data, 4)
        self.showing_price['text'] = str(self.price)


def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! а что делает функция super?

Comment: класс App наследует класс Tk и вот эта строчка super().__init__() позволяет обращаться к любому методу и атрибуту Tk через класс App что прекрасно доказывает следующая строка self.title('Курс валюты') Можно ещё и так Tk.__init__()

Comment: Вам помог ответ на вопрос? Так примите его ;-) А нажав на стрелочку вверх  вы таким образом проявите симпатию к ответу ну и наоборот.